# A test should fail on throwing exception

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

```
@Test
    public void testA() throws Exception {

}
```

Is above a good style to code ? Because the test is allowed to throw exceptions and if the code throws exception, then Netbeans consider that as a successful test case.

If yes, then I want to make the test fail if it throws any exception, how can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean "successful" test case? JUnit tests fail by default if they throw an exception.

Comment: @chrylis unfortunately, it didn't in my case and I thought may be `throws Exception` is the culprit.

Comment: Post the code; a bug in your test is more likely than a bug in JUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid if you want the test to *fail* if *any* exception occurs. Imho this is good style if a checked exception may be thrown in the test code, but should not occur.

---

If you wish to test exception generation on a specific line or wish to verify something on the exception itself, this pattern is usually more helpful:

```
@Test
public void testA() {
    // Initialize
    try {
        // Except Exception here
        Assert.fail("Exception not thrown");
    } catch (IWantToCatchException ex) {
       // Assert exception is correct
    }
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To pass a test when an exception is thrown you need to set the expected element of the `Test` annotation.

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class)
```

Otherwise jUnit will fail the test if an exception is thrown, which may be appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Since JUnit 4.7 there is the `expected` part in the annotation of tests:

```
@Test(expected=YourException.class)
```

With this the test succeeds only if the exception is thrown.

Therefore, if you leave `expected` out, the test fails whenever an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are the rare cases which you don't know will happen or not, but you take precautions. But in case of unit testing if you are assured of that it will throw certain exception then test it that way like :

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)  
public void testA() {  
  int i = 1/0;
}
```